# How can I trigger OnPlayerConnected while using NetworkManager Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity-networking

I am using UNet and NetworkManager component. I am trying to when the player connected to server just say to me 'I am connected'. I must serialize that. I am using NetworkBehaviour, I think this may lead to failure. But how can I serialize that ?

Here is my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System.IO;
using UnityEngine.Networking;
public class MultiPlayerOyunKontrol : NetworkBehaviour
{

    void OnPlayerConnected(NetworkPlayer player)
    {
        Debug.Log("Player  baglandi"+this.transform.name);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `OnPlayerConnected` function is not even part of UNet API. It's part of Unity's legacy network API. This is how should have been be used:

```
public class MultiPlayerOyunKontrol : MonoBehaviour 
{
    void OnPlayerConnected(NetworkPlayer player)
    {
        Debug.Log("Player  baglandi"+this.transform.name);
    }
}
```

not

```
public class MultiPlayerOyunKontrol : NetworkBehaviour
{

    void OnPlayerConnected(NetworkPlayer player)
    {
        Debug.Log("Player  baglandi"+this.transform.name);
    }
}
```

Basically, `OnPlayerConnected` has nothing to do with `NetworkBehaviour` so it wouldn't work unless you are using the old Unity network API which you're not.

Below is a proper way to see when client is connected or disconnected with UNet:

```
void Start()
{
    NetworkServer.Listen(9000);
    NetworkServer.RegisterHandler(MsgType.Connect, OnConnected);
    NetworkServer.RegisterHandler(MsgType.Disconnect, OnDisconnected);
    NetworkServer.RegisterHandler(MsgType.Error, OnError);
}

public void OnConnected(NetworkMessage netMsg)
{
    Debug.Log("Client Connected");
}

public void OnDisconnected(NetworkMessage netMsg)
{
    Debug.Log("Disconnected");
}

public void OnError(NetworkMessage netMsg)
{
    Debug.Log("Error while connecting");
}
```

Comment: Thank you!! NetworkServer.Listen(9000); is a port number of course, isn't it ?

Comment: Ye. Its the port number you create the server with. You can use any number that is free on the machine.  Also, when you are not sure about something check the doc. For example, [`NetworkServer.Listen`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.NetworkServer.Listen.html) doc.

Comment: @veereshkumbar Please create a new question with your script and describe what's no working

Comment: @Programmer i am following the way what you have described for Unet but not working. What i wanted is the same as NurullahCelik, i want to know when a client is connected to server please help

Comment: Like I said, this problem is solved. Create a new question with your complete script and explain what does not work. I will take a look at it. OP's problem was about OnPlayerConnected. Your problem is about OnConnected not working. Without your script I can't help you.