# How to know wether the client and server are connected to each other in Unity Networking

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, networking, client-server, multiplayer

Here I am creating a multiplayer game with Unity Networking. What I want is to start the game when both Server and client is connected. In my game I have 2 players one will act as a server who hosts the game and the other acts as a client who connects to that host with the servers IPAddress. So when both are connected and ready to play i want to start the game. Can anyone help me how can i get to know that both are connected.

Here is the code what I am using.

```
public NetworkManager manager;

public void startServerr()
{
NetworkServer.Listen(9000);
    NetworkServer.RegisterHandler(MsgType.Connect, OnConnected);
    NetworkServer.RegisterHandler(MsgType.Disconnect, OnDisconnected);
    NetworkServer.RegisterHandler(MsgType.Error, OnError);
    manager.StartHost();
}

public void connectToServer()
{
    manager.networkAddress = PlayerPrefs.GetString("oppPlayerIP");
    manager.StartClient();
}

public void OnConnected(NetworkMessage netMsg)
{
    Debug.Log("Client Connected");
}

public void OnDisconnected(NetworkMessage netMsg)
{
    Debug.Log("Disconnected");
}

public void OnError(NetworkMessage netMsg)
{
    Debug.Log("Error while connecting");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are currently using `NetworkManager`... If you prefer to use  `NetworkManager` over `NetworkServer` and `NetworkClient` that requires [manual](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43677544/3785314) registering of the events, then your script must inherit from `NetworkManager`.

Once you inherit from `NetworkManager`, you can then override and use [`OnClientConnect`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.NetworkManager.OnClientConnect.html) and [`OnServerConnect`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.NetworkManager.OnServerConnect.html) functions to check when client is connect to server and when server is connected to client respectively.

Here is an example:

```
public class NetTest : NetworkManager
{
    private NetworkManager manager;

    public void startServerr()
    {
        manager = this;
        manager.StartHost();
    }

    public void connectToServer()
    {
        //manager.networkAddress = PlayerPrefs.GetString("oppPlayerIP");
        manager.StartClient();
    }

    public override void OnClientConnect(NetworkConnection conn)
    {
        //base.OnClientConnect(conn);
    }

    public override void OnClientDisconnect(NetworkConnection conn)
    {
        //base.OnClientDisconnect(conn);
    }
    public override void OnServerConnect(NetworkConnection conn)
    {
        //base.OnServerConnect(conn);
    }

    public override void OnServerDisconnect(NetworkConnection conn)
    {
        //base.OnServerDisconnect(conn);
    }
}
```

You can find more network callback functions in the public function section [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.NetworkManager.html).

Comment: As i know about Network Manager Methods OnClientConnect is fired on the client. OnServerConnect is fired on the server. But what i want is to fire a single Method both side.

Comment: **"But what i want is to fire a single Method both side"** When I write answer, I write to answer what's in the title and body of the question. If the question is not clear, I comment to ask for more details before adding answer. My answer answered what's in your question which is *"know wether the client and server are connected"*...You can use a **simple**  boolean variable get whatever you are looking for. Happy coding!

Comment: please have look at the question "know wether the client and server are **connected to each other**" not seperate. and I mentioned " Can anyone help me how can i get to know that both are connected."

Comment: Can you put this on your Network spawned prefab object, or will that fail?

Answer (score 0):

First of I recommend you reading all the documentation about unity networking before actually trying to make a connection. After you've done that you should know how to handle this request. If you don't know by then here is how to handle this specific request.

First you need to let the server handle all incoming connections by using the method *OnConnected(NetworkMessage netMsg)*.
You should be able to recognize the individual players connected to the server.
Now you only need to create a ready button and send the ready status towards the server when clicked. If every player connected has send his isReady message towards the server you can start the game. this is done by sending a message from the server towards all the connected clients.

Hope this helps, any questions just ask.